# Locate modules by stack address

Tags: c++, exception, windows-mobile, stack-trace

I have a Winodws Mobile 6.1 application running on an ARMV4I processor. Given a stack address (from unwinding an exception), I like to determine what module owns that address.

Using the ToolHelpAPI, I'm able to determine most modules using the following method:

```
HANDLE snapshot = ::CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_GETALLMODS, 0 );
if( INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != snapshot ) 
{
    MODULEENTRY32 mod = { 0 };
    mod.dwSize = sizeof( mod );
    if( ::Module32First( snapshot, &mod ) ) 
    {
        do {
            if( stack_address > (DWORD)mod.modBaseAddr && 
                stack_address < (DWORD)( mod.modBaseAddr + mod.modBaseSize ) )
            {
                // Found the module!
                // offset = stack_address - mod.modBaseAddr
                break;
            }
        } while( ::Module32Next( snapshot, &mod ) );
    }
    ::CloseToolhelp32Snapshot( snapshot );
}

// if it's still not found

snapshot = ::CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS | TH32CS_SNAPNOHEAPS, 0 );
if( INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != snapshot )
{
    PROCESSENTRY32 proc = { 0 };
    proc.dwSize = sizeof( proc );
    if( ::Process32First( snapshot, &proc ) ) 
    {
        do 
        {
            if( stack_address > proc.th32MemoryBase &&
                stack_address < ( proc.th32MemoryBase + 0x2000000 ) )
            {
                // Found the executable
                // offset = stack_address - proc.th32MemoryBase
                break;
            }

        } while( ::Process32Next( snapshot, &proc ) );
    }
    ::CloseToolhelp32Snapshot( snapshot );
}
```

But, I don't always seem to be able to find a module that matches an address. For example:

```
stack address        module       offset
0x03f65bd8      coredll.dll + 0x0001bbd8
0x785cab1c        mylib.dll + 0x0002ab1c
0x785ca9e8        mylib.dll + 0x0002a9e8
0x785ca0a0        mylib.dll + 0x0002a0a0
0x785c8144        mylib.dll + 0x00028144
0x3001d95c           my.exe + 0x0001d95c
0x3001dd44           my.exe + 0x0001dd44
0x3001db90           my.exe + 0x0001db90
0x03f88030      coredll.dll + 0x0003e030
0x03f8e46c      coredll.dll + 0x0004446c
0x801087c4              ???      
0x801367b4              ???      
0x8010ce78              ???      
0x801086dc              ???      
0x03f8e588      coredll.dll + 0x00044588
0x785a56a4        mylib.dll + 0x000056a4
0x785bdd60        mylib.dll + 0x0001dd60
0x785bbd0c        mylib.dll + 0x0001bd0c
0x785bdb38        mylib.dll + 0x0001db38
0x3001db20           my.exe + 0x0001db20
0x3001dc40           my.exe + 0x0001dc40
0x3001a8a4           my.exe + 0x0001a8a4
0x3001a79c           my.exe + 0x0001a79c  
0x03f67348      coredll.dll + 0x0001d348
```

Where do I find those stack addresses that are missing? Any suggestions?

Thanks,
PaulH

Edit: By taking @SoapBox's suggestion, I've filled in some of the gaps with "my.exe"

Comment: Is that function returning all of the modules you expect?  Perhaps its missing something important (like your main program, or kernel32, or something)...  Also shouldn't your address comparisons  be <=/>= instead of </>?

Comment: @SoapBox - Interesting. No, it doesn't. 1 item is missing. My application is a DLL that is loaded by a .exe. That .exe is missing from the list.

Comment: It looks from the addresses that more than 1 library is missing so that's probably not your answer, but perhaps it accounts for a some of what is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CPU stack contains more than just addresses of code.  Function arguments get passed on the stack as well.  Only a debugger would know exactly what's in the stack frame, it gets it from the .pdb file.  That won't really help you, a program cannot debug itself.  On regular Windows, you'd use a minidump to do postmortem analysis, no idea if that's available on Mobile.  It should be.

Comment: Are you saying those 0x80000000 addresses don't refer to code? What sort of things could they refer to?

Comment: @PaulH:  Data, as I explained. Could be float arguments.